# Unit testing postgres database tools

Tags: postgresql-9.1

Which is the best tool for postgresql testing ?
I am newly placed in a company where my role is this. I want to know some info regarding tools.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are still looking for a testing suite. I am facing the same problem as you were and found a couple of testing suites on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#PostgreSQL).

Looks like only [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/) is still actively developed. To me it seems to have a steep learning curve but I think in the long run it will pay to use such a tool for automated testing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new one on GitHub called Plpgunit.

https://github.com/mixerp/plpgunit/

> Plpgunit does not require any additional dependencies and is ready to
>   be used on your PostgreSQL Server instance.

To install this framework, you will have to run the SQL script file. So, it seems easy to give a try.